jQuery - see if the same text appear on both lists and add class to list item if match
I try to check if text on list_1 is present on list_2 and add class "show" to the each list item if text is found.
On below example class "show" should be assigned to item lists  "This is text c" & "This is text e" as the same text exist on the list_1
However in my case class "show" only appear for last item list "This is text e"
HTML:
<ul class="list_1">
  <li>This is text c</li>
  <li>This is text e</li>
</ul>


<ul class="list_2">
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text a</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text b</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text c</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text d</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text e</li>
</ul>

Script:
$(function(){

var showTag;

$('.list_1 li').each(function(){
      showTag = $(this).text();
});

$('.list_2 li').each(function(){
   if($(this).text()==showTag)
       $(this).closest('li').addClass('show');
});

});


showTag only hold the value of the last item.
You should compare the ones inside the loop.

Here is a pure JS solution:


const list_1_values = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('.list_1 > li') ].map(li => li.innerHTML);
const list_2_doms = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('.list_2 > li') ];

list_2_doms.forEach(li => {
  if (list_1_values.includes(li.textContent)) {
      li.classList.add('show');
  }
});
.show { color: green; }
<ul class="list_1">
  <li>This is text c</li>
  <li>This is text e</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list_2">
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text a</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text b</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text c</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text d</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-fw fa-square"></i>This is text e</li>
</ul>




Thanks i would never come up with this solution! I forgot to mention on list_2 there are also icon tags (i've updated my code) and it looks like because of them script isn't working. Sorry i missed them before and i would really appreciate if you could alter your script so it works with my edited code, THANK YOU

I've updated my answer @Maciej, since it's a child,  i've used textContent on the li to get the child content
